# Expand containing div when dragging an item inside it and reaching limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

My page has several items (divs) that are draggable and resizable. 
My code for doing this is given below:

```
part.draggable(
                     {
                                containment: 'parent',
                                drag: function(event, ui){
                                partIsDragging = true
                                part.prev().css('top', ui.position.top - 20 ).css('left', ui.position.left )
                                part.prev().show()
                           },
                                stop: function(event, ui) {
                                         partIsDragging = false
                            }
                              }).resizable({
                                 containment: 'parent',
                                 handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw,n,w,e,s',
                                 stop: function() {
                                            }                                        
                              });
```

The html structure for these is the following:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="draggableItem"></div>
    <div class="draggableItem"></div>
    <div class="draggableItem"></div>
    <div class="draggableItem"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

In my css files i have set body height: 100% and wrapper height: 100%. Width is always fixed for wrapper, width: 950px. I want my div to expand in height when the draggableItem reaches the bottom of the wrapper. Right now when the page is loaded, it has the height as big as the resolution allows it but in case I have more items in the wrapper then everything becomes cluttered and I would like when dragging an item to somehow expand the wrapper in height dynamically. This should happen only if I hit the bottom border.

PS: I am using jQuery and jQuery-ui.

Comment: can you post your relevant css as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have a solution.  First off, I replaced `part` with `'.draggableItem'` and `this` where appropriate.  Please tell me if that breaks the code in some critical way.  In addition, I removed `part.prev().css('top', ui.position.top - 20 ).css('left', ui.position.left )` in the code below.

```
function adjustWrapperHeight(movingObject)
{
    var objectBottomPosition = $(movingObject).offset().top+$(movingObject).height()
    var wrapperBottomPosition = $("#wrapper").offset().top+$("#wrapper").height()
    if(wrapperBottomPosition-objectBottomPosition<distanceBuffer)
    {
        $("#wrapper").height($("#wrapper").height()+distanceBuffer+1)
    }
}

var distanceBuffer = 20;
$('.draggableItem').draggable(
        {
            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(event, ui)
            {
                partIsDragging = true
                adjustWrapperHeight(this)
            },
            stop: function(event, ui)
            {
                partIsDragging = false
            }
        }).resizable(
        {
             handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw,n,w,e,s',
             resize: function(event, ui)
             {
                adjustWrapperHeight(this)
                var objectRightPosition = $(this).offset().left+$(this).width()
                var wrapperRightPosition = $("#wrapper").offset().left+$("#wrapper").width()
                if(wrapperRightPosition<=objectRightPosition)
                {
                    $(this).width(ui.originalSize.width)
                    var containmentLeftPosition = wrapperRightPosition-$(this).width()
                    $(this).offset({top:$(this).offset().top,left:containmentLeftPosition})
                }
             }                                    
         })
        })
```

The function `adjustWrapperHeight(movingObject)` adjusts `div#wrapper`'s height depending on a `movingObject`'s bottom position.  That is, when `movingObject` "pushes up" against `div#wrapper`'s borders, it adjusts `div#wrapper`'s height.

I had to use a hack for `resizable`.  The `containment: 'parent'` for `resizable` (but not `draggable`) sets the containment to the container's **ORIGINAL** height or so it seems.  That means as the height of `div#wrapper` dynamically changes, the constraint set by `containment: 'parent'` does not dynamically change.  To fix this, I removed `containment: 'parent'` and indeed the entire `containment` and ensured that `div#wrapper`'s right containment isn't broken within the `resize` event.  Note that you should probably do this with `div#wrapper`'s left containment as well.

Please tell me if this was helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: your solution worked nice! thank you for this amazing thing you made! I have adjusted the code to suite my needs, since i'm dealing with multiple wrappers and divs that need to be draggable and resizable i had to add another argument to the adjustWrapperHeight function, that is the wrapper object that needs to be resized.